# Paypal API / Adaptive Payments - Set Payee/Receiver

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

With the Adaptive Payments API it is very simple to set the payee/receiver of a transaction. As the Adaptive Payments API is being deprecated, has the functionality to specify the payee been added to the REST API yet?

Comment: Have you managed to find an answer to this yet?

Comment: I ended up using Adaptive Payments. As far as I know, REST Payment doesn't allow direct p2p transfer. You can probably accept money and then use the Payouts API though

Comment: The problem with Adaptive Payments is, that PayPal say the following "Important: Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product. It is restricted to select partners for approved use cases and should not be used for new integrations without guidance from PayPal."  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: Is there a better solution, seeing that PayPal don't recommend it?